# setColor not working after Android 10 (API 29) upgrade

Tags: java, android, paint

My code

```
paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

was successfully running before upgrading to Android 10. Now it throws an error:

> Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ID, must be in the
>   range [0..16)

(Looks like the error message is trimmed)

Nevertheless,

```
paint.setARGB(255,255,255,255);
```

works fine.

I've read that starting API 29, setColor also accepts long color values, I tried explicitly putting

```
paint.setColor(parseInt(0xFFFFFFFF));
```

or

```
paint.setColor(valueOf(0xFFFFFFFF));
```

but none of them worked...

Any solutions in how to use setColor? ARGB doesn't always work for me (e.g. cannot create gradient by specifying ARGB).

Comment: Say, why does this question have the `javascript` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with a cast:

```
paint.setColor((int)0xFFFFFFFF);
```

...although I'm unable to reproduce this behavior on my own machine... 0xFFFFFFFF is always interpreted as an `int` (even though it's out of range, strictly speaking). Not sure why your compiler is choosing the `setColor(long)` override.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it says "missing ) after argument list"...

Comment: Mmmm hmmm... and are you sure you have all the parenthesis in there?

Comment: Looks like the problem is in compiler - it does not understand casting... It is a kinda "real-time" compiler on Android itself, that has limited functionality. I'm sorry for bothering with such a situation :)

Comment: Sounds interesting. If you feel like you want help with that, just add the information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this.

```
        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this,R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter value is treated as long number so it cant calculate the color space. There are two different functions, valueOf(int) and valueOf(long). Just cast to int to get working with standard int value.

```
valueOf(0xFFFFFFFF.toInt())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 paint.setColor(Color.pack(Color.parseColor("#00ffff")));
```

android  SDK >=  29

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
paint.color = resources.getColor(R.color.black10)
```

or

```
paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black10);
```